# PHPdbg Installation error

Tags: php, phpdbg

I am New to phpdbg. I am trying to install phpdbg using following steps: which is mentioned on site [phpdbg](http://phpdbg.com/docs/introduction)

```
cd /usr/src/php-src/sapi
git clone https://github.com/krakjoe/phpdbg
cd ../
./buildconf --force
./config.nice
make -j8
make install-phpdbg
```

on the fourth steps i.e. when I try to do :

```
bash: ./buildconf: No such file or directory
```

From where I have to run this command.

Comment: http://www.litespeedtech.com/support/forum/threads/recompiling-php-according-to-wiki-works-but-not-with-litespeed.454/

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade : I did't got you:(

Comment: Have you go through the link?

Comment: Do you mean I required to recompile my PHP?

Comment: The buildconf script should be available. If you did a checkout inside your php src/sapi folder. And moved up a level when the checkout is completed.

Comment: @tlenss : I tried it from 3 directories i.e form php-src,sapi and form  phpdbg then also it is showinf same error.

Comment: If you download a source archive from php.net and extract it. You will find the `buildconf` script in the root of the extracted folder

Comment: I have not downloaded source archive from php.net

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 5.5 and homebrew, do this...

`brew install php55 --with-phpdbg`

I think it's also supposed to work for PHP 5.4 and PHP 5.6 (*may be on by default*).